# Button radio option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an HTML form option through the old "Yes or No" way, and once I had a code that was working good. But now, it is not.

I want to make two buttons, one for each option, and they should be get the `active` class when clicked, and also change the `<input type="hidden">` value.

It correctly changes what the `hidden` value is, but it is acting more like a checkbox. I want it to only one be active at a time.

HTML:

```
<div class="controls">
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio" data-toggle-name="lab">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" value="TRUE"
            type="button" checked>Yes</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" value="FALSE"
            type="button">No</button>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="lab" id="lab">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
 jQuery( function ( $ ) {
$( 'div.btn-group[data-toggle="buttons-radio"]' ).each( function () {
 var group = $( this );                    
 var name = group.attr( 'data-toggle-name' );
 var hidden = $( 'input[name="' + name + '"]');
 $( 'button' , group ).each( function () {
     var button = $( this );
     if ( button.val() == hidden.val() ) {
         button.addClass( 'active' );
     }else{
         button.removeClass( 'active' );
     }
     button.click(function () {                        
         hidden.val($( this ).val());
     } );
 } );
 });
 });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/y2Mbg/2/) is a JSFiddle at the momment.

What am I missing?

Please, avoid just simple answers. It could solve my problem, but I want to understand what is wrong or what I forgot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NadeemAfana got what I was missing, but the fiddle is not working. Posting here if any one else get on the same problem.

Removed the `else` statement and added `$("button").removeClass( 'active' );` after the on click call.

[**Test it here**](http://jsfiddle.net/y2Mbg/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not mark the buttons as "active" when a button is clicked. You are only updating the state when the page loads.

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/y2Mbg/4/

```
 button.click(function () {  
     $("button").removeClass( 'active' );
     hidden.val($( this ).val());
      $(this).addClass( 'active' );
 } );
```

Comment: If I don't marked them when it is clicked, how can I click and see the classes being added?

Comment: When you click on any button, you need to mark that button as active and unmark all other buttons (remove the active class).

Comment: By the way, I can't see your Fiddle.

Comment: Click on the Run button.

Comment: I know, I mean, it is not doing what it should.

Comment: I understood what you said, and I agree. But it not working at this way.

Comment: +1 Because you got what I was missing. The only reason I will not accept is because the Fiddle is not working properly.

Comment: You should only consider code on Stackoverflow page.

Comment: Ok, but by Fiddle, I meant a way to test it and not the the link itself. I got your code and couldn't make it run. But understanding what you said, I've puts things where they should be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( 'button' , group ).each( function () {
     var button = $( this );

     button.click(function () {                        
         hidden.val($( this ).val());
         button.addClass( 'active' );
         button.siblings('button').removeClass( 'active' );
     } );
 } );
```

Comment: Alone it have the same behaviour, and inside it does not change the class.